# what's the max singleton object size ? android

Tags: android, singleton

I have this singleton in my application :

```
 class singleTon{
         private static singleTon myInstance;
         private ArrayList<City> cities;
         private ArrayList<Category> categories
         private ArrayList<Business> businesses;

        private singleTon()
       {
       }        

        public static singleTon getInstance(){

           if(myInstance == null)
           {
                myInstance =  new singleTon();
           }
           return myInstance;
        }

        public ArrayList<City> getCities(){
         return categories;
        } 

        public void setCities(ArrayList<City> cities){
             this.cities = cities;
        }

    }
```

This code work fine on galaxy s5 , but sometimes it crashes on galaxy s3 when the app runs in the background (Null pointer exception).
So when I deleted categories list and businesses list it worked fine on both smartphones.
Does the operating system delete the singleton object when it's very large ?

the crash report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.net.screens.MainView.setIDsOfLayout(MainView.java:467)
at com.example.net.screens.MainView.onCreate(MainView.java:80)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
```

Comment: where is your constructor `singleton()`?

Comment: Null Pointer Exception is usually not related to memory issues... Please give stackTrace.

Comment: Android does only kill complete applications running in the background. It will never kill a single instance of your application though.

Comment: Now we have a logcat, but not the code which the logcat is pointing to

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the categoires or businesses anywhere? Do you have a getter and setter for them also? My money is on them never being initialised and throwing a NPE when trying to access them. You should initialise them to new lists in the private constructor.

```
private singleTon(){
    cities = new ArrayList<City>();
    categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    businesses = new ArrayList<Business>()
}
```